# Updating a table row multiple values oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I m struggling to update one column for a table with a sub query. I have a table where currently one of the values is null.
Currently I have:

```
UPDATE DW1_PURCHASES SET DW1_PURCHASES.TOTAL_AMT = 
(
SELECT DW1_PURCHASES.QUANTITY * DW1_PRODUCTS.PRICE 
FROM DW1_PURCHASES, DW1_PRODUCTS 
WHERE DW1_PURCHASES.PRODUCT_ID =  DW1_PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_ID
)
```

Although subquery returns data which I need to insert I get a error of single row subquery returns multiple rows.How do I basically shift subquery result to the table?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to `JOIN`the update table inside the `sub-query`. Just `correlate` the `sub-query` with update table

```
UPDATE DW1_PURCHASES 
SET DW1_PURCHASES.TOTAL_AMT = 
(
SELECT DW1_PURCHASES.QUANTITY * DW1_PRODUCTS.PRICE 
FROM  DW1_PRODUCTS 
WHERE DW1_PURCHASES.PRODUCT_ID =  DW1_PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_ID
)
```

**Note :** If your `DW1_PRODUCTS` table has duplicated `PRODUCT_ID` then even now there is a possibility to get the same error